# Unable to Update User: UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Greetings from a Parse Neophyte: 
**Task:** Update current user's attributes (in Parse's User table).

**Problem:** Received the 'UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError' error.

Here's my code:

```
func updateParseUser(newUser:User, sender:UIViewController) {

    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

    if ((currentUser) == nil) {
        return
    }

    if let location = newUser.location {
        currentUser["location"] = location
    }

    if let phone = newUser.phoneNumber {
        currentUser["phone"] = phone
    }


    currentUser["displayName"] = "Turkey"

    PFUser.currentUser().save()

}
```

Result:

```
Error: Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError (Code: 206, Version: 1.5.0)
```

Do I need to create a session or something?

Remedy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your SDK. I had the exact same issue. When I updated to 1.6.0 the issue resolved itself.